# How can I find a special element on a page?

Tags: java, html, selenium

I am getting started with selenium. I opened the url and entered my username and password: [Tribal Wars 2](https://de.tribalwars2.com/page#/). The Problem is to reach this button to click:

```
<a href="#" class="btn-orange btn-border small-icon" ng-click="selectCharacter(w.charId, w.id, w.loginDisabled)" tooltip="" tooltip-if="w.loginDisabled" tooltip-content="Diese Welt wurde geschlossen." ng-class="{'btn-grey': w.loginDisabled}" <span class="icon" <span class="icon-inner character" ng-class="{ 'character': playerId === w.ownerId, 'coop': playerId !== w.ownerId, 'locked': w.loginDisabled }"</span </span <span class="wrapper align-left" <span class="text character ng-binding"Rammboss</span <span class="text world ng-binding"Leeds Castle</span </span </a
```

Java Code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"wrapper\"]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[ 1]/div[3]/div[ 1]/ul/li/a")).click();
```

### Error Message:

> Starting ChromeDriver (v2.9.248315) on port 20436 Exception in thread
>       "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element
>       (Session info: chrome=53.0.2785.143)   (Driver info:
>       chromedriver=2.9.248315,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING:
>       The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command
>       duration or timeout: 39 milliseconds For documentation on this error,
>       please visit: seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
>       Build info: version: '2.43.1', revision:
>       '5163bceef1bc36d43f3dc0b83c88998168a363a0', time: '2014-09-10
>       09:43:55' System info: host: 'AGBioSA04', ip: '10.4.1.81', os.name:
>       'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version:
>       '1.8.0_102' Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
>       Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false,
>       chrome={userDataDir=C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir4760_1168},
>       takesHeapSnapshot=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true,
>       version=53.0.2785.143, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false,
>       nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true,
>       webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true,
>       javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}] Session ID:
>       5f87f399ba0889cb549ffc090b9dffbf    at
>       sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at
>       sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at
>       sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>       at
>       org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:204)
>       at
>       org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:156)
>       at
>       org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:599)
>       at
>       org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:352)
>       at
>       org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:449)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:357)  at
>       org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:344)
>       at com.mysite.selenium.HomePage.fillField(HomePage.java:46)     at
>       com.mysite.selenium.HomePage.main(HomePage.java:58)     at
>       sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)     at
>       sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at
>       sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>       com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)

This Game is written in Php and Javascript. **Is it possible to do this with selenium?**

Comment: There isn't much 'special' about such elements. I'm guessing your selector is simply not right. isn't there a simpler, better maintanable selector (perhaps a css selector)? Did you try out the xpath selector in chrome (e.g. using `$x("//*....")` console or ctrl+f in the element view)?
 Another thing that could go wrong here, is there might be a timing issue and you might need to use implicit/explicit timeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to wait for your element after login.

```
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10); // Wait for 10 seconds.
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"wrapper\"]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[ 1]/div[3]/div[ 1]/ul/li/a")));
 WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"wrapper\"]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[ 1]/div[3]/div[ 1]/ul/li/a"));
 element.click();
```

1. First line creates the instance of webdriver wait and uses "10" to
   wait for 10 seconds.
2. The second line is telling selenium to wait until the element
   specified appears. Again, it will wait for 10 seconds.
3. The 3rd line finds the element and calls it "element".
4. The 4th line clicks on the element.

Hope that helps.

Edit: Just incase you have trouble with finding xpaths - 
In chrome:

1. Right click on the element on the webpage and click inspect
2. The HTML for the element should be highlighted
3. Right click on the highlighted section
4. Hover over 'copy'
5. Click Copy xpath

Comment: Yeah, u are right, problem was to wait for the element, thx! :)

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Tried the xpath on chrome console and there is an issue with it.

You can simply use this xpath to click on the 'More Information' / 'Mehr Informationen' button

```
//div[@class='more-info']//a
```

If you are trying to click on the login button, use one of the following xpaths

```
//button[span[.='Login']]
```

Or

```
//button[@class='button-login']
```

Also, although the xpath in the question is incorrect and doesn't return any matching nodes, for future reference, don't specify the double quotes in your xpath, I.e \"wrapper\". Use it this way instead:

```
//*[@id='wrapper']
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use selenium regardless of in which language application under test developed. Selenium works at black box level so it doesn't have any relation to the codebase of web application.

Regarding your problem, from exception, either element locator is wrong or you need to wait for element to be present. You can use firbug and firepath in firfox to ensure your locator is valid and pointing to correct element.

These are the common things you need to take care while providing automation implementation. One need to understand that selenium or webdriver is the api and provides a way to interact with web/mobile application under test. To overcome from all other testing needs and general automation challenges you should create base framework that takes care or start using available existing framework like [QMetry Automation Framework](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf)